# An expression to mean 'Thanks for that'

Tags: expressions

I can't recall exactly.. someone was saying something like..
To mean "Thanks for that" is it "I have you to thank for that" or "You have me to thank for that"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have you to thank for that!

This phrase means that the reason that "that" happened, is because of you. We can use the phrase to mean:

- That was because of you. Thank you.

However, you need to be a bit careful, because sometimes we use this phrase sarcastically, or idomatically to mean that something is somebody's fault!

- Oh no, Mark's not coming to the party
- You've got Mary to thank for that. She was shouting at him yesterday. I don't think he'll come if she's coming.

So, if you want to use this phrase to show that you appreciate something somebody did, you need to make sure they won't think your blaming them for something!

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: When someone says "I have you to _do something_" is it up to the context to know who is the subject of the to-infinitive?

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks for that

Simply means that you are thanking someone for something s/he did for you as a favor.

Let's build and example:

Lisa was unable to take her big bag from a conveyer belt. Mike helped her. After a week, when they meet, remembering the incidence, Lisa might say...

> You really helped me then. Thanks for *that*.

I took an example of *past* because I don't think *'thanks for 'that''* is a common reply for the favor done *just now*. More commonly, we use just *Thanks* or *Thank you*.

But to address your question, in any context, *thanks for that* is you thanking someone for the favor done. It's kinda: `"I thank you for that [the favor]"`

Comment: Ah... I think I didn't write clear enough.. I'm sorry. I just wanted to know which was right, 'You have me to thank for that' or 'I have you to thank for that' to mean 'Thanks for that'.

Comment: Who 'thanks'; 'You', isn't it? But getting into such nuance is making simple things complex, I guess! ;)

Answer (score 0):

A **patronising** way to say '**thank-you**'.

It's subtle sarcasm of course, and often used to be blatantly rude - or even faux-innocently - which is why it's often used by British people whilst exercising *snark*. e.g. Someone might tell you a story you are not interested in, or see yourself too aloof to even consider any interest in the lesser mortal.

**Posh person is thinking** -

> You really think I'm interested in spoutings from your grubby little
>   self from the gutter? My goodness, gosh no, not on your nelly.

**Says** -

> Thanks for that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's not _always_ sarcastic though - I have sincerely said "Thanks for that".

Comment: That's true. Context is important. It can also be used in a similar way to "OK" after someone sends you a long email – a politer way to reply _tl;dr_ (Too long; didn't read).

Comment: I think you see a negative connotation that I don't see. If I'm at a party, and a friend "rescues" me from someone who has been talking at me for a while, I might lean over and whisper "Thanks for that". "That" is just a way to concisely refer to whatever it was you're thanking the person for. I could have said "Thanks for saving me from that conversation" but it doesn't lend itself to a quick whisper.

Comment: I get what you are saying. Maybe you are from the US where sarcasm is not so common. I was in NYC one time and a complete numpty was telling me how he got sold a 'meal deal' on the street, and I told him "I guess he saw you coming" - and he was like "yeh yeh, I guess he saw me coming" not noticing I was taking the piss.

No one does 'snark' like Londoners. Type in "what British people really mean" in to Google images, and you'll see an image there with examples - that's my train of thought. http://www.estetica-design-forum.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=8326&d=1342624337